# Best textbook on philosophical background of interpretations (for beginners)

Tags: references, interpretation, philosophical

I'm looking for the best textbook teaches basics of statistics for a general researcher (undergraduate) without totally ignoring the mathematical proofs and theories while the main emphasizes is on how those mathematical concepts can be used to interpret the real world examples and why such interpretations are meaningful, when not and how to know the difference.